# spidev_test.c analysis

Tags: pic, raspberry-pi, c, spi, data-transfer

I'm trying to connect a Raspberry Pi with a PIC32 through SPI. For RPi I'm using the spidev_test.c code (I'm modifying it to suit my needs) but... because I'm a novice in programming hardware, I'm having a hard time understanding the full code in spidev_test.c

Here's the spidev_test.c:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/spi/spidev_test.c

If you can, I would appreciate it if you guys can explain to me just how this code works.
More exactly, I would like to know the following things:

1. How does the ioctl() function work? What does it return?
2. Does the open() function return 1/0?
3. What is the parse_opts() function for?
4. Detail on the spi_ioc_transfer structure. Does it store in rx_buf the first element of the array's address?
5. In function transfer(), how does the transfer work exactly? I mean, does the sending occur in the declaration of the tr structure? Where's the receiving? (This is the most bothersome question of all for me)

Comment: This is a better fit on superuser or Ask Ubuntu. It likely will be closed here, since pure API discussions are off-topic.

Comment: @Madmanguruman I think stackOverflow as it is a pure C and Linux kernel programming question.

Comment: Hmm. Stack Overflow seems closer to pure programming to me (a specific programming problem; a software algorithm; software tools commonly used by programmers; practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession). I'll stick with Ask Ubuntu.
.

Comment: @Madmanguruman Little chance that AU is going to answer kernel source code questions, it is pretty much a stack for end user questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code you refer to is actually a Linux command line utility. What you are looking for are the Linux `man` pages. They are easy to access when you are on a Linux system, by just typing:

- [`man 2 ioctl`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ioctl)
- [`man 2 open`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open)

Also:

- `parse_opts` is a function in the source code you link to, just analyze the source and be sure to look at [`man 3 getopt_long`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long) which is the main command in that function. It basically interprets the command line options given to the tool.
- [`spi_ioc_transfer`](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/spi/spidev.h) is mentioned in the header file, but unsure about how to go from there.
- `transfer()` is a function in the source code you link to, just analyze the source and be sure to look at [man 2 ioctl](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ioctl) which is the main command in that function.

Last but not least check [the documentation for spidev](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/spi/). A lot of documentation is available from kernel.org, just add your `site:kernel.org doc` to Google search term.